# Animate SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, svg

Can I rotate an SVG path via the point of it's origin with an animation? I've tried using CSS keyframes on svg groups but that makes the path disappear. Ideally I don't want to be using javascript but if there's no other way I will.

The path is inside a css styled parallax which might be messing with the SVG viewbox as the coordinates don't seem right.

Comment: You can use the following addresses for example: [SVG animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_animation_with_SMIL) and [SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm using here ES6 class.

```js
var NS="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";  
var SVG=function(el){
    return document.createElementNS(NS,el);
}
 
 svg = SVG('svg');
    svg.width='100%';
    svg.height='100%';
document.body.appendChild(svg);


class myPath {
     constructor() {
     this.path=SVG('path');
     var d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 ";
     this.path.setAttribute("d", d);
     this.path.setAttribute("fill", "#F7931E");
     this.path.addEventListener("click",this,false);
   }
   get draw(){
       return this.path;
   }
 }
 
 myPath.prototype.rotate = function(x) {
   return svg.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(svg.createSVGMatrix().rotate(x));
}

myPath.prototype.animate = function() {
       self = this.path;
       self.transform.baseVal.appendItem(this.rotate(5));
};

 myPath.prototype.handleEvent= function(evt){
  self = evt.target;  
  console.log(self.getAttribute('d'));
     
 self.move = setInterval(()=>this.animate(),100);
       
}

svg.appendChild(new myPath().draw);
```